# Why do pages not load for one user but do so for me if we use the same login?

Tags: users

A user (who has nearly the same rights as the admin account) logs in and gets the page below.  He cannot access any links to perform his duties.  The screen shot is below.  However, I am able to use the same username and password on my end and I get no errors when I log in or when I click on links--pages come up perfectly.  Yet, he has to keep hitting the back button in his browser for something to eventually come up.  He's tried different browsers, internet connections, computers, etc.  All have the same negative result.  Does anyone have an idea why Drupal is behaving this way? why would the results be different if we are both logging in using the same account and thus with the same permissions? (not at the same time, of course).

It appears to have to do with the 302 document has moved, but it doesn't explain why it hasn't moved for me, but yet it has for him.

[image: Unable to load]

Comment: Does he have the same problem if he changes the browser he uses?

Comment: Do you have any local DNS overrides related to this site (most likely in your hosts file)?

Comment: @Triskelion Yes, he's tried several browsers, the results are all the same messed up page.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong I will have to ponder on this one, but the same DNS overrides that he gets are the same as the ones I would get, right?  So help me understand how it would make a difference?  I am not saying it would make a difference, I just don't know.

Comment: I don't know your setup but sometimes people will demo/test a development site by pointing the live domain to it in their local hosts file. So when they enter a URL request it comes from a different server to the public one. This is one cause of the symptom where a site works for one person but not for others.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the 0 at the beginning of the output. It is illegal character there. It can confuse browsers, and it seems it's the case for your user. Find a code part that outputs it and remove it, and you should be good.

Second thing - it seems he would fall into infinite redirect loop if not that 0. Page he sees under ntu.tipplers.org.uk says it's 302 redirect to ntu.tipplers.org.uk - possible bad thing, unless I'm missing something. Carefully examine redirect modules you're using. If it's only about adding `/` at the end, consider moving this rule to `.htaccess` as it is way faster and this rule will be called great many times. If it is indeed a loop, find out in your settings why he sees it, and you do not.

Comment: You have some good leads here, could you tell me what you mean by "Find a code part that outputs it"?  I don't know that means or at least how to go about it.  I will look into the other redirect modules and .htaccess and see what I can clean up. By process of eliminating one possibility after another, I'm hoping to find the culprit.

Comment: Somewhere there is `echo 0`, `echo $somevariable` with variable == 0, `?>0` or something like that. Probably custom module, custom theme or text with php filter applied. I'm sorry to say, but this kind of mistake is hard to track.